# How to Install and enable VNC server on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: vnc

I am trying to find an easy straight forward method to install VNC server on my Ubuntu 15.10 VM.  I've tried using the built-in desktop sharing and not working for me.

Is there an up to date method anyone know of?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have `vino` install it from the terminal by using `sudo apt-get install vino` and then following the prompts. After you've installed it, you will probably want to reboot. You can start it without rebooting (I believe) but I do not recall how and Google isn't being very helpful.

When you reboot, again, open the terminal and enter `vino-preferences` and it should open up a GUI interface where you can change your settings. One of the settings that I prefer is to enable the icon all the time. It's then easier to access it.

Comment: Sounds so easy!  :)  I get this error from TightVNC client.  "Error in TightVNC Viewer:  No security types supported.  Server sent security types, but we do not support any of their."  I can ping the ip address no problem.  What could it be?

Comment: @Oneil - Is this on a LAN or are you going to do this over the internet? (I don't have and haven't had this problem. So I'm not 100% sure where to go from here.) If it's on a LAN then do **not** forward the ports on your router and try changing the security settings? I can try to replicate this on a VM if needed but that will take me a little while.

Comment: Thanks again.  This on my LAN.  Should be simple.  I can ping it (ESXi VM) no problem.  Still working on it...

Comment: Try the TigerVNC viewer/client. If no connection happens then try to change  the security settings - all the way off and then tighten them up as you go.

Comment: Ha, finally got it.  There is a require encryption option for vino that needed to be unchecked.  Good for now.  Thanks for responding!  http://www.libregeek.org/2014/04/29/getting-remote-access-work-ubuntu-14-04-vino/