# Confirming vnc server is working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, vnc

I have installed vnc server via the following command, following from [this online guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
```

It seems that vnc server installation expects the file ~/.Xresources, which does not exist on my Ubuntu 16.04. The vnc log file says (observe the last log line):

```
> 17/08/17 21:24:15 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10 17/08/17 21:24:15
> Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group 17/08/17 21:24:15 Copyright (C)
> 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge 17/08/17 21:24:15 All Rights
> Reserved. 17/08/17 21:24:15 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for
> information on TightVNC 17/08/17 21:24:15 Desktop name 'X' (matan:1)
> 17/08/17 21:24:15 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t,
> 3.8t 17/08/17 21:24:15 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901 Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring Font
> directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring xrdb: No
> such file or directory xrdb: can't open file '/home/user/.Xresources'
```

The installation *does leave* a vnc process running (Xtightvnc), but I am unable to connect from a remote client. Is the above a real error/problem? or should I interpret that my vnc server is installed and running correctly?

*My vnc clients* (a local RealVNC client, and an iPad VNC app) *fail to connect so I am unsettled on what my actual status is.* They complain about authentication, but may probably fail for other reasons, I'd not trust their error messaging too much, given the vnc server log under `.vnc` doesn't show any signs of connection attempts!

Perhaps you'd also recommend a good procedure for confirming the server is properly working, for 16.04? maybe a vnc client that should work against the above vnc server out of the box?

People have suggested plainly using vino instead. Here is my vino configuration, and I've fiddled different ones too; my VNC clients over the same LAN fail to connect, and I'm unsure how to determine if vino is really operable on my Ubuntu desktop. Going down the path of enabling vino logging seems [way too hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829710/where-are-the-logs-of-the-gnome-vino-server) to my taste.

[image]

Comment: I'd rather use Vino server  (https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline).

Comment: @Redbob that old post seems to deal with arcane versions. Have you possibly used Vino server on 16.04?

Comment: They have different purposes: if you are trying to relay an existing physical display (i.e. **share** your local desktop) then use `vino` (or `x11vnc`); if you're trying to run a separate remote X session, use `xtightvnc`. AFAIK the message about `.Xresources` is just informational.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it in 16.04 and 17.04 too. It works the same way. There is another link: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/693634/how-to-install-and-enable-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Well, I already had vino installed all along (it comes with Ubuntu, I think). Which viewer would you recommend to go along with it, to locally verify it is working then? I added my vino config to the original question now (above).

Comment: I don't recommend connecting a VNC client to a desktop-sharing VNC server on the same machine to "locally verify" it - it will get *very* confusing ;)

Comment: Why not, won't it just open in a new window? how would you otherwise confirm it is working, before troubleshooting all the firewalling and security configuration impediments you may have?

Comment: Any iPad VNC app anyone cares to recommend? I only have an iPad on the local network, to test with

Comment: Ideally you would attempt to connect from another machine on the same NAT'ed LAN - ideally you would **not** expose an unfiltered VNC port to the public internet.

Comment: Can't connect from another machine on the same LAN (thanks though).